# Wire.endTransmisson crashing when building Arduino Library

Tags: arduino, i2c

I am trying to have a constructor set up the pins on the external chip I am using to be outputs. To do so I need to do an I2C transaction.
Below is code that is currently in the constructor. With the `Wire.endTransmisson`line in the code, it crashes. With it omitted it works. But I feel that it should be in there and something else is going on. Is there something I am missing here?

```
HID::HID(){
Wire.begin();
I2Cflag = 1;
Wire.beginTransmission(0x41);
Wire.write(0x03);
Wire.write(0xF3);
Wire.endTransmission(); //When omitted, it works!
I2Cflag = 0;}
```

Comment: Is it crashing when compiling or when you are running the sketch?

Comment: It compiles and runs but when it reaches the like of code `Wire.endTransmission` its halts